# CocoaPod Dependencies of Dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm developing a CocoaPod with a dependency on an external library, defined in my Podfile as:

```
pod 'somePod', '~> someVersion'
```

I can then run `pod install` to install the Pod.

However, when installing my pod into another application, the header files from somePod are not included.  I'm assuming this is a podspec issue with exported header files.  Below is a snippet of my podspec:

```
s.source_files  = "MYPOD", "MYPOD/**/*.{h,m}"
s.public_header_files = "MYPOD/**/*.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dependency in the podspec itself like this:

```
spec.dependency 'somePod', '~> someVersion'
```

See here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency